# Cursor over dynamic textfield fails to track

Tags: cursor, movieclip

I am having a problem and i am not sure what to do although the answer must be obvious..

I have a movieclip and inside the movieclip a dynamic text field.
I want to move the moveclip when my cursor is inside it but the problem is the area of the textfield isn't recognized as part of the movieclip although its in it. This results the movieclip to stop when the cursor touches the textfield area. Any suggestions? :(

Comment: your question is missing a language tag; which language?

Comment: sry for that, its AS3. i figured it out, i just disabled the mouse events inside the movieclip.